# Stack corruption during conversion of large double to unsigned int

Tags: c++, casting, double, corruption

On a windows machine, running visual c++, I discovered that the following lines of code seem corrupt memory via a call to something called __dtoui3 (a bunch of bytes change after this call. Specifically it seems like the value of DBL_MAX is printed twice in a row in a random place in memory)

```
double temp =  DBL_MAX;
unsigned int blissfullyUnaware = (unsigned int) temp;
```

The following, however, do not:

```
double temp =  0;
unsigned int blissfullyUnaware = (unsigned int) temp;
```

Can anyone shed light on why this is happening?

Comment: This code invokes **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: (1) We need to see a _complete program_ that can be compiled and run. (2) You don't really have `\`` characters after each assignment to `temp`, do you?

Comment: The type `int` is usually 32 bits, and its range is to small to hold `DBL_MAX`. Try using `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: if you used a proper c++ cast like `static_cast` you'd find this probably doesn't even compile

Comment: @zwol no you don't

Comment: @user3457614 No I don't what?

Comment: @zwol I don't think a full copy of code is necessary, the problem statement is clear. Also do you know what __dtoui3 is? The problem seems to be in there. Undefined or not, memory should not be corrupted.

Comment: @user3457614 A full copy of code is always necessary to diagnose memory corruption; very often, the bug is _nowhere near_ where it appears to be.

Comment: @zwol in this case I've done the hard part and isolated the part of code causing the memory corruption and don't feel like going on a useless tangent.

Comment: @user3457614 If you are seriously asserting that the two lines of code you showed, _all by themselves_, corrupt memory, you should make it 100% clear that that is what you are doing by adding the additional three lines of code required to make them a complete program (i.e. `#include <limits.h>`, `int main(void) {`, and `return 0; }`.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> **[conv.fpint]/1** A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is **undefined** if the truncated value **cannot be
>   represented** in the destination type.

Emphasis mine. `DBL_MAX` is somewhere around 2^1024, while `unsigned int` likely tops out at 2^32.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure the compiler isn't changing the C cast to a `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @user3457614 more than likely the compiler is [morphing your cast into a `reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) which is bad news as it can have lots of odd behaviors. I would suggest using explicit C++ style casts and not C casts.

Comment: @Mgetz No, C-style cast here behaves the same way as `static_cast`, per **[expr.cast]/4** . `reinterpret_cast<int>(someDouble)` wouldn't even compile.

Comment: I have to say that the behavior reported by the OP ("printed twice in a row in a random place in memory") strikes me as poor QoI even for undefined behavior.  Write an unspecified value to the result, fine; fire SIGFPE or equivalent, also fine; corrupt unrelated memory, not fine.